# C++ Security Framework for Buffer Overflows, Format String Bugs and Integer Overflows

Tags: c++, integer, buffer, overflow, overrun

Does anyone know of any C++ security frameworks which protect against buffer overflows, format string bugs and integer overflows please?

Comment: Good, but the question is, is it possible?

Comment: @MM I don't know if it is possible.  My dissertation supervisor told me to develop two security frameworks: one for the web and one for C++.  I found plenty of frameworks for the web, however it seems that there aren't a lot for C++

Comment: You can't really get 100% protection from those. There are tools like StackGuard, which uses canary values to detect stack overflows (heap overflows are a different matter), and StackShield, but they're both subvertable. This might be a good place to start -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a standard feature of current Microsoft compilers, except for the format string bugs. Those aren't really C++ bugs but C bugs. C++ formatting solutions are generally typesafe.